# Drupal 10 : Why my private contenttype's fields are viewable by anonymous?

Tags: drupal, drupal-modules

I made a custom contenttype in drupal UI, and I want it to be available only for editors so I don't check the box "published" when I'm on my custom_contenttype_edit_form.
I grant to editors the permission "see unpublished content" and I don't grant it to anonymous.
With this, I can see my custom_contenttype as an editor, and I got a nice "access forbidden" message when I try to access it as an anonymous : OK, cool.

Now, I need to create a public page that lists all titles of this private customtype.
I declare a new route, and in my controller, I query the entitytypemanger to get all my customtype objects and I take care of using "->accessCheck(FALSE)" because my customtype is private and I want to make a public list of those titles.

It works BUT my problem is that it also works with "->accessCheck(TRUE)" which is not the behavior I expect. Maybe all the fields of my private contenttype are available to anonymous ?

There must be something I'm doing wrong, but I can't figure out what it is.
Thanks
Ben